# DRF: Username still required after customizing Abstract User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a REST API using Django and DRF. I'm trying to create a user model and use it in my application. But the problem is that it returns a 400 error status code which says:

> {"username":["This field is required."]}

This is my code for models:

```
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from api.fileupload.models import File


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField('Email address', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name', default='', max_length=255)
    phone_no = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=255, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField('Address', default='', max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField('Country', default='', max_length=255)
    pincode = models.CharField('Pincode', default='', max_length=255)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The Serializer:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = None

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['username'] = uuid.uuid4()
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.country = validated_data.get('country', instance.country)
        instance.pincode = validated_data.get('pincode', instance.pincode)
        instance.phone_no = validated_data.get('phone_no', instance.phone_no)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('email',)
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'password', 'email', 'name', 'phone_no', 'address', 'country', 'pincode',      
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: Did you register your user model in the settings? It will be something like: ```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appName.UserModel'```

Comment: FWIW, I have a custom user model that is defined as ```class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):```

Answer (score 1):

> class User(AbstractUser):

As your `User` model inherits from [AbstractUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dee687e93a2d45e9fac404be2098cc4707d31c1f/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L316), it will inherit 
the [username](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dee687e93a2d45e9fac404be2098cc4707d31c1f/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L325) field.

Just remove the `username` field from your `User` model by setting `username = None` like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # ...
    username = None
    # ...
```

---

> class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):

As your `UserAdmin` model inherits from [django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1de9a92295af87846e810a40fbb9ceb6b8d3e773/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L41), you will need to update [fieldsets](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1de9a92295af87846e810a40fbb9ceb6b8d3e773/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L44), [list_display](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1de9a92295af87846e810a40fbb9ceb6b8d3e773/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L61), [search_fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1de9a92295af87846e810a40fbb9ceb6b8d3e773/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L63), and [ordering](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1de9a92295af87846e810a40fbb9ceb6b8d3e773/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L64) fields in your `UserAdmin` model because they use `username` which you have removed from your `User` model.

Comment: <class 'api.users.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'users.User'.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check!

Comment: maybe he can just store the email in username field which is not uncommon. That will remove all of problems.

Comment: Yes, that is doable!

Answer (score 1):

Abstract User always has the username field. Removing it will cause problems. I will suggest you store the email address of the user in username field as well and use that. Please make sure its always updated in both fields which is not very hard.